# Email reply to multiple email addresses not working

Tags: wp-mail

I want that email reply should be received at multiple email address. But it is not working for me. I have tried different ways but none of these working for me. I am trying this header but it is only replying to the last email address.

```
$to = "recipientemail@address.com"; 
$subject = "my email subject";
$message = "my email message";
$headers = array();
$headers []= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers []= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers []= "Reply-To:  <" . $EmailAddress1 . "> <" . $EmailAddressss2 . ">" . "\r\n" ;
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I have tried without braces as well but this one is also not working

```
$headers []= "Reply-To: 1st@address.com,2nd@address.com\r\n";
```

I do not have much idea about this so little guidance about this will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Unfortunately this is not widely supported**, not because WordPress does not support it, but because most email clients do not support it, so it cannot be relied upon.

Instead, consider using a mailing list and use the mailing lists address as the reply to field

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I will try mailing list now.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The email RFC does support it.  See [Derek Snider's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/349715/220621)

Comment: I've amended my answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually, RFC 5322 (from 2008) allows for this:

RFC 5322 section-3.6.2: ( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2 )
'In either case, an optional reply-to field MAY also be included, which
contains the field name "Reply-To" and a comma-separated list of one or
more addresses.'

And if you think this is new, even RFC 822 (from 1982) says:
'If the "Reply-To" field exists, then the reply should go to the addresses indicated in that field and not to the address(es) indicated in the "From" field.'

So Reply-To DOES allow for multiple addresses. It's just that some clients unfortunately do not adhere to the RFC... tsk tsk tsk.

You can only have one Reply-To header line, but that line can have unlimited addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is true however many of my tests on Outlook and Yahoo indicates that all email addresses are dropped after the comma. Only the first email address is being used to populate the "To" field.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/241653)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).